# Many nested scrolling callbacks are not fired/called?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm still fairly new to advanced customization in Android UI. What I'm trying to achieve is create something like a `SwipeRefreshLayout` - This layout is not good as what I want (about how flexibile it is, because we cannot easily change the refreshing indicator which means we seem to have to stick to what it provides - the default loading circle indicator).

Also trying to recreate that kind of layout is good for learning, so I really need to do it myself. The problem here is about nested scrolling callbacks, they are `DispatchNestedScroll`, `OnNestedScrollAccepted`, `OnStartNestedScroll`, `OnStopNestedScroll`, ... They are all not fired/called no matter what I've tried.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class PullToRefreshLayout : ViewGroup, Android.Support.V4.View.INestedScrollingChild, Android.Support.V4.View.INestedScrollingParent
{
   public PullToRefreshLayout(Context context) : this(context, null, 0) {

    }
    public PullToRefreshLayout(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    {
        NestedScrollingEnabled = true;            
    }
    public PullToRefreshLayout(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        nsChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        nsParentHelper = new NestedScrollingParentHelper(this);
        NestedScrollingEnabled = true;
    }
    NestedScrollingChildHelper nsChildHelper;
    NestedScrollingParentHelper nsParentHelper;
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 0)
        {
            var content = GetChildAt(0);
            content.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
    public override bool NestedScrollingEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            //return base.NestedScrollingEnabled;
            return nsChildHelper.NestedScrollingEnabled;
        }

        set
        {                
            nsChildHelper.NestedScrollingEnabled = value;
        }
    }
    //Here are just some included callbacks which are never called
    public override void OnNestedScrollAccepted(View child, View target, [GeneratedEnum] ScrollAxis axes)
    {
        base.OnNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes);
    }
    public override void OnNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed)
    {
        base.OnNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed);
    }
    public override void OnNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed)
    {
        base.OnNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
    }
    //and more ...
}
```

The custom view wraps a simple `ListView` (like as how we use the `SwipeRefreshLayout`), something like this:

```
<CustomViews.PullToRefreshLayout
     android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/listView1"/>
</CustomViews.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

So I expect that when scrolling the ListView back and forth, at least some of the nested scrolling callbacks should be fired, but none of them. Before I can fulfil the feature of my own pull-to-refresh layout, I need to make some appropriate callbacks be triggered at the right moment.

Finally the code is run against a Visual Studio Emulator running Android 6.0 (I believe the problem is still present on lower versions of Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` does not support nested scroll, since `ListView` does not implement [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html).
So nested scrolling callbacks will never be fired/called.

I recommend you to use `RecyclerView`, `NestedScrollView` or other views that implements `NestedScrollingChild` instead of `ListView`

**NOTE:**

`SwipeRefreshLayout` supports `ListView` by implements `onTouchEvent` 
, not by nested scroll. Here is [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/432f3317f8a9b8cf98277938ea5df4021e983055/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java#L981)

Comment: I think you might misunderstand something here. I'm trying to recreate the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and it does work on a `ListView` (wrapped inside).

Comment: I add note to my answer. `SwipeRefreshLayout` supports `ListView` by `onTouchEvent` , not by nested scroll.

Comment: OK, sorry I misunderstood the source code, I did not even understand why there are a large amount of code related to nested-scrolling, which is fairly complicated to me (maybe I cannot imagine the situation in which we need to handle the nested-scrolling for the pull-to-refresh behavior to work properly).

Comment: If the child view of SwipeRefreshLayout  is NestedScrollChild, nested scroll events are propergated to SwipeRefreshLayout. In this case, the code in onTouchEvent is skipped by first `if statement` in onTouchEvent, and nested scroll events are handled.

Comment: Maybe, the code in onTouchEvent is something like backports or support code for non NestedScrollingChild.